# Rolling 3 months DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have had a headache since yesterday with a measure.

My table is `Data` and in this table, I have a column `Data[Date]` which contains the first day of each month from January to June and a measure which calculates `Total revenue`.

I need a measure that calculates for June: `Total REV = April + May + June`.

I have tried this measure:

```
CALCULATE([TOTAL REV], DATESINPERIOD(Data[Date], LASTDATE(Data[Date]), -3, MONTH))
```

but in order to have the correct number I need to select all three months in the slicer, not just the month I am interested in.

Comment: Can you post your `[Total revenue]` measure? Your formula should work if it's something like `SUM(Data[Revenue])`.

Answer (score 2):

When you've got just one date selected in the slicer the filter context for the `CALCULATE` is just that month.

So I suspect that something similar to the below would fix your issue as it would allow the `CALCULATE` to consider the whole date table:

`CALCULATE([TOTAL REV], DATESINPERIOD( ALL(Data[Date]), LASTDATE(Data[Date]), -3, MONTH))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sumx(DATESINPERIOD('Data'[Date], LASTDATE('Data'[Date]), -3, MONTH) , [TOTAL REV])
```